# Facebook like button group connection issue

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

Recently I got the idea to link my forum to facebook so I could get more traffic, but when I changed the href URL to the group (http://www.facebook.com/?sk=group_166066160111619) it kept giving me errors... Is there any way to link my facebook group with my site to allow likes?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your approach, linking the group URL to the Facebook developer page, and got the same error that you explained above.
If you open your Facebook group, you will see that there is no like button link there, instead it has a "Join group" link. Therefore I guess it is not possible to have a like button pointing to this group. However, you can have a like button pointing to a Facebook page (not a group), as Facebook page has a like button in the profile page. The following page http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=10674 discuss about similar issues.
Hopefully Facebook will provide solution for this soon. Hope this helps !

Comment: Hi, I tried to simulate this by taking your URL http://www.facebook.com/?sk=group_166066160111619 and create a dummy like button for that URL and put that on my website. When I clicked on that, it showed me the error message that the URL cannot be reach. But then I opened my facebook profile, I noticed that it displayed a post in my profile that "I liked your group page". So I believe that it is with the Facebook back-end system that causing this error. I'll submit a bug report for this issue to Facebook now.